# Create custom form in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I am using `Edit` and `SimpleForm` from `react-admin`. How do I create a custom form to allow customised `action` and `type` on submit?

App.js

```
<Resource name="category" list={CategoryList} edit={CategoryEdit}  />
```

index.js

```
<Edit actions={<CategoryEditActions />} title={<CategoryTitle />} {...props} >
    <SimpleForm>
      <DisabledInput source="id" />
      <DisabledInput source="code" />
      <TextInput source="name" />
   </SimpleForm>
```

Here the api call would be `/category/:categoryId` with `PUT` request. I want to modify url to `/category/:categoryId/test` with method as `POST`. Is there any way to customize this?

I have handled this in my CustomDataProvider -

```
 case UPDATE:
             if(resource === 'category'){
                    options.method = 'POST';
                    url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}/test`;
                } else {
                    options.method = 'PUT';
                    url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
                }
                break;
```

Is there any other way to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the job of your `dataProvider` in `react-admin` (`restClient` in `admin-on-rest`). You'll have to create a custom one:

- For `react-admin`: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#writing-your-own-data-provider
- For `admin-on-rest`: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#writing-your-own-rest-client

You'll have to check the resource and type then build the fetch options by yourself.

Comment: I had handled url and method type in the custom data provider. I have edited my question to show the case. Is it the only way to do so?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way

Comment: Thanks @gildas, you are a saviour